# Widi (Wireless Display) set up on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, display

I recently purchased a  Sony Vaio S Series Ultrabook that comes with Wireless Display.  The steps to set this up on Windows 8 seem to be well documented but I haven't come across how to set this up on Ubuntu.  Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: widi not supported. DLNA may work http://askubuntu.com/q/152695/35775